# Torsion module Finite composition length

Tags: modules, dedekind-domain

> Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain. $A$ be a finitely generated R-module. Then $A = A_1 ⊕ A_2$,for some torsion module A 1 and torsion-free module $A_2.$ Prove that $A_1$ has finite composition length.

I can see why $A_1$ has ACC, but I can not prove $A_1$ has DCC.
This is from *Module Theory, Extending Modules, and Generalizations. Theorem 4.12.*

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain and $M$ a torsion module over $R$. Then $M$ is a finitely generated module over the ring $S = R/ \operatorname{Ann}_R(M)$, and any composition series of $M$ over $S$ is a composition series over $R$. Note that $\operatorname{Ann}_R(M)$ is non-zero because $M$ is torsion, and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Artinian_ring&oldid=1055534593) it follows that $S$ is a (principal) Artinian ring. As described on the same page, it follows from Hopkins' theorem that $M$ is of finite length over $S$, and therefore over $R$.

---

Here is an alternative approach.

**Proposition.** Let $R$ be a noetherian ring, and $M$ a finite $R$ module.
Then $M$ is of finite length if and only if $\operatorname{Ass}_R(M) \subseteq \operatorname{Spm} R$.

[Recall that the set of *associated primes* of $M$ is $\operatorname{Ass}_S(M) = \lbrace \mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec} R : \mathfrak{p} = \operatorname{Ann}_S(m) \text{ for some } m \in M \rbrace$.]

*Proof.*
By [00L0](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00L0), there exists a filtration by submodules $$ 0 = M_0 \subset M_1 \subset \cdots \subset M_n = M $$ such that each quotient $M_i /M_{i-1} \cong R/ \mathfrak{p}_i$ for some $\mathfrak{p}_i \in \operatorname{Spec} R$. Now, there are two cases:

1. Each $\mathfrak{p}_i$ is maximal. In this case, each quotient $M_i / M_{i-1}$ is simple, so the chain $M_\bullet$ is maximal. By [00J3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00J3), it follows that the length of $M$ is $n < \infty$.
2. There is some $\mathfrak{p}_i$ that is not maximal. Then $R/ \mathfrak{p}_i$ is an integral domain that is not a field. Take any non-zero non-unit $x\in R/ \mathfrak{p}_i$. Then $R/ \mathfrak{p}_i \neq (x) \nsupseteq (x^2) \nsupseteq (x^3) \cdots \neq 0$ is an infinite chain of submodules of $R/\mathfrak{p}$, which corresponds to an infinite chain of submodules between $M_{i-1}$ and $M_i$. So the chain $M_\bullet$ can be refined to a chain of arbitrary length. In particular, $M$ does not have finite length.

Now we need to make a connection between the above and $\operatorname{Ass}_R(M)$.
By [02CE](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02CE), $\operatorname{Ass}_R(M)$ is precisely the set of minimal primes among $\lbrace \mathfrak{p}_1,\dots,\mathfrak{p}_n \rbrace$. So $\operatorname{Ass}_R(M) \subseteq \operatorname{Spm}R$ if and only if each $\mathfrak{p}_i$ is maximal. $\Box$

**Corollary.** Let $R$ be a noetherian domain of Krull dimension 1, and $M$ an $R$-module that is finite and torsion. Then $M$ has finite length.

*Proof.* Since $R$ has dimension 1, any associated prime of $M$ is either 0 or maximal. $M$ being torsion, $0 \notin \operatorname{Ann}_R(M)$, so $\operatorname{Ann}_R(M) \subseteq \operatorname{Spm}R$. $\Box$

Comment: The "according to wikipedia" obscures a lot, because it's not clear what you're looking at to decide it's Artinian. In fact, it _is_ true that $S$ is Artinian (it's semisimple Artinian, even) so I believe you. I'm just curious to see where that "according to wikipedia" part shows up.

Comment: I was referring to the following bullet point under "Examples and Counterexamples":
"If $I$ is a nonzero ideal of a Dedekind domain $A$, then $A/I$ is a principal Artinian ring."

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!  good job on this post, too.